# Using Archimedian properties, show how $.9999\dots $ = $1.00000\dots$

Tags: real-analysis

There is no shortage of great answers proving the equality (if that's the correct math terminology) and maybe, in essence they are doing it this way.

I would please appreciate help to show using Archimedian properties how

$$.9999\dots\ = 1.00000\dots$$

and that there are no infinitesimals between $1$ and $.9999\dots$.

By infinitesimals I mean, for example $f(x) = 1/x$ in the set of rational functions, which is greater than $0$, but less than any constant function.

Thanks

Comment: If you're in a theory where there are infinitesimals, then there _are_ infinitesimals (or, at least, $1-{}$ infinitesimals) between $0.999\ldots$ and $1$ (at least all systems I've seen). The Archimedean principle basically states, however, that the real number line has no infinitesimals, and only infinitesimals can fit between there..

Comment: @Arthur Thanks, I hadn't realized that distinction.

Comment: @Arthur I wonder if it is accurate to say there are $\omega$-many $9$s after the decimal point?

Comment: If $x$ is a real number or an integer, then $1\over x$ is always a real number, which means it isn't an infinitesimal, because $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't contain infinitesimals. There are other number systems (eg hyperreals, surreals) that contain infinitesimals.

Comment: If you define your symbol $0.999...$ in any way as a real number you will see that it is equal to the real number $1$. Now pick your definition of symbol $0.999...$

Answer (score 1):

Archimedian properties$$\forall x>0 , y \in \mathbb{R} :\exists n \in \mathbb{N} ,nx> y \to  n \geq \lfloor\frac yx\rfloor +1\\$$
$$
x=0.999999...,y=1.0000\\nx>y \to \\n \geq \lfloor\frac {1.00000...}{0.999999...}\rfloor +1$$ Is this what you mean ? or something like this  ?

Comment: Thanks, as a beginner, I hadn't seen the floor notation in this context, yet you certainly have produced a viable $n$. Perhaps you would please add to your answer to using this to show the equality.